# How do you filter IP addresses on AWS API Gateway?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

This is not strictly related to [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/) per see, but more related to AWS I guess.

My intention is to block everyone from accessing a Lambda, by putting a resource policy on my API Gateway (API GW) to restrict access based on IP addresses. I have the following code in my serverless.yml:

```
apiGateway:
    resourcePolicy:
      - Effect: Deny
        Principal: "*"
        Action: execute-api:Invoke
        Resource:
          - execute-api:/${self:provider.stage}/*/mypath
        Condition:
          NotIpAddress:
            aws:SourceIp: # Allowed IP's
              - "allow.some.ip.address"
              - "allow.another.ip.address"
```

If I execute `serverless deploy` then it completes successfully. When looking in the AWS portal however I see no resource policy attached to the API GW. When trying a POST request to my endpoint, it indeed works from *any* IP address which clearly is *not* what I want.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong or missing here? I'm also curious to know how serverless knows which API to attach my policy to.

I'm using the simplified syntax for specifying the resource, and I've been following these two guides, so I think my code should work but it doesn't:

- [How do I allow only specific IP addresses to access my API Gateway REST API?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-resource-policy-access/)
- [API Gateway resource policy examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, so posting the answer here if anyone else reads it.

The code I pasted in the question was correct per see, I had just placed the entire `apiGateway` under the `custom` section in my serverless file. Placing it under `provider` instead solved it, and successfully created the resource filter under my API GW and now blocks IP addresses properly!